# How to depict Import a file action in the Sequence diagram

Tags: object-oriented, uml, sequence-diagram, diagrams

Everyone says sequence diagrams are so easy but I just cannot figure this out. Basically user clicks on an 'Import from temp folder' button, the program opens a window with a list populated with filenames, user clicks on a filename, clicks on OK and the document is imported.
I know the order of the actions but how to depict e.g. populating a list, or selecting an item from a list?

So I assume the objects would be like:

```
[USER]  [ImportDialogWindow]    [ListOfFiles:STRING]   [?where to go with selected file]
```

Answer (score 1):

- The file will be a message between these timelines. They will send it to each other.
- But IMHO the sequence diagram on that low level for so simple tasks is excessive. Or the coder doesn't know, that he should read item and after that put it into a list?